# java database object level security

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate

I want to put spring security on database object level,i know spring provides solution for this and i can create four tables and then i have to map my data to these tables also.This is an extra overhead as size of tables grows as per actual data.

Is there any other solution or framework in java?

Basically i want to put certain filters on every database query like

if i have following roles :

Admin

Teacher

Student

Now if i am going to fetch subjects for user then i have to put following restrictions :

Admin : No filter

Teacher : subjects which he teaches

Student : subjects which he read

These filters should be applied on every query fired in subject table.

Answer (score 1):

Spring security ACLs does exactly what you want. It is not really the easiest part, but it is really powerful. Once it is configured, you simply add security at method level (usually in a service layer, that is between the UI and the database) by simply adding annotations.

My advice would be :

- first setup spring security without acl, but with a database store
- read the doc for the ACLs part
- add the relevant tables to your databases and initialize them *by hand*
- read again the doc and test

You can also find a tutorial at http://krams915.blogspot.fr/2011/01/spring-security-3-full-acl-tutorial.html, but I never used it.

Comment: yes spring security ACL is right thing but think there are two issues in this :

1. i have to map all my database tables with ACL database

2. ACL database size will grow as the size of actual data grows.

Comment: For point 1 : you have to refer to relevant entity tables (the one for which you want to add security) in ACLs table - you own tables do not change . Point 2 : that's true, but unless many users access many entities, the size of the ACL base is generally far under the size of the business one. But you are true : it is a nice tool, not **the** tool to use in any use case.